# issues with daterangepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the daterangepicker and having some issues while running it

I am using the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/19xnfkp6/1/

the above is thro0wing error on the library undefined, not sure why, on my local its working, but the concept is the same

I am using this code

```
$('.iDate').daterangepicker({
            singleDatePicker: true,
            showDropdowns: true,
      locale: {
                    format: '#ucase(session.dateMaskFormat)#',  
                    "separator": "/",
                    daysOfWeek: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
                    monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                    firstDay: 1
                }
            
        })
```

with this approach, if i select a date of `Sept 01, 2023` which when selected enters as `01/09/2012`

and when i submit it, it goes as `Jan 09, 2023`

I am literally lost with this plugin as to what is going on and how to figure out this issue

Comment: I think it's just a problem of locales. 01/09/2023 => 1st of September 2023 in french

Comment: In your fiddle you do not have the CDN ( jQuery, Moment.js and Date Range Picker's files) included.  Did you read the documentation [here?](https://www.daterangepicker.com/)

Comment: @dalelandry I saw that they were included. If you click on the left navigation where it says resources. Although including jQuery that way probably isn't the best but it was an attempt to include

Comment: Generally speaking, I throw the CDNs into the actual HTML block at the top when using JSFiddle ..  Not to mention the version of jQuery included is severely out of date .. `1.12`

Answer (score 0):

In JSFiddle ...  It's sometimes a bain to use their native inclusions.  Instead just put your JS and CSS at the top of the HTML block.

[See This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3goe6u52/)

```js
$('.iDate').daterangepicker({
  singleDatePicker: true,
  showDropdowns: true,
  locale: {
    format: '',
    "separator": "/",
    daysOfWeek: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    firstDay: 1
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input id="demo" class="iDate" name="demo">
```

Comment: but the question still stays at the same, it transforms the date, why it is doing that and how can i fix it